# How to paginate two tables in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to ask if i can use will_paginate plugin two times on one page? For example i have table with male users and table with female users on one page or in one view and I need paginate both tables. My question is what is the usual solution of this problem?

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a `:param_name` option to tell will_paginate the name of the parameter to use for the page number within URLs (the default is `:page`). So you could do:

```
<%= will_paginate @males,   :param_name => 'males_page' %>
<%= will_paginate @females, :param_name => 'females_page' %>
```

- [will_paginate documentation](http://gitrdoc.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/master/)